# Linux: FIT flat image tree format execute a script

Tags: linux, u-boot

Hello I'm trying to include a script inside the FIT image. script works and just print an hello world.
This is the part included into the .its file

script@1 {

```
    description = "Bootscript";
    data = /incbin/("/home/dvdk/lynx/boot_original.scr");
    type = "script";
    rch = "arm";
    os= "linux";
    compression = "none";
    load = <0x81000000>;
    entry = <0x81000000>;
};
```

FIT is loaded in 80000000 and the iminfo command returns:

Checking Image at 80000000 ...
   FIT image found
   FIT description: Simple image with single Linux kernel and FDT blob
    Image 0 (script@1)
     Description:  Bootscript
     Type:         Script
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x800000e0
     Data Size:    489 Bytes = 489 Bytes

Then I tried to execute this script with the 'source command'
IF i use:
$ source 80000000:script@1 I obtain:
syntax error
Unknown command ' �域� ��� �域� ���.....

While if I execute:
$ source 800000e0 the script is correctly executed.

Can anyone help me with this issue, or suggest me where to find help or solutions. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The fact that running the script using simply the data address works indicates that you have added a legacy uImage script file inside the fitImage.

Try to create the fitImage using the script in text format instead:

```
script@1 {
    description = "Bootscript";
    data = /incbin/("/path/to/your/script.txt");
    type = "script";
    compression = "none";
};
```

You should then be able to run it with the fitImage syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's need to be removed the following lines:

```
arch = "arm";
os = "linux";
load = <0x81000000>;
entry = <0x81000000>;
```

I tried a FIT script, and it worked fine with just `data`, `type`, and `compression` entries.